# How to create a spring boot rabbitmq consumer for a python sender?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I want develop an application where in the python code sends the message using rabbitmq and the consumer is Spring boot rabbitmq code.

sender.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pika
import sys

connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host='localhost'))
channel = connection.channel()

channel.exchange_declare(exchange='topic_logs',
                     exchange_type='topic')

routing_key = sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) > 2 else 'anonymous.info'
message = ' '.join(sys.argv[2:]) or 'Hello World!'
channel.basic_publish(exchange='topic_logs',
                  routing_key=routing_key,
                  body=message)
print(" [x] Sent %r:%r" % (routing_key, message))
connection.close()
```

How do I configure a rabbitmq receiver using spring boot? What are the necessary configurations required at the receiver side? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class So49512910Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So49512910Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public Queue queue() {
        return new Queue("someQueue");
    }

    @Bean
    public TopicExchange exchange() {
        return new TopicExchange("topic_logs");
    }

    @Bean
    public Binding binding() {
        return BindingBuilder.bind(queue()).to(exchange()).with("whatever.topic.pattern.you.want.to.match");
    }

    @RabbitListener(queues = "someQueue")
    public void listener(String in) {
        System.out.println(in);
    }

}
```

Or, if the exchange already exists...

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class So49512910Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So49512910Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public Queue queue() {
        return new Queue("someQueue");
    }

    @Bean
    public Binding binding() {
        return new Binding("someQueue", DestinationType.QUEUE, "topic_logs", "rk.pattern", null);
    }

    @RabbitListener(queues = "someQueue")
    public void listener(String in) {
        System.out.println(in);
    }

}
```

Comment: Wow. Thank you so much Sir. This was what I was looking for. Your answers are so clear....helping me a lot, thanku:)

Comment: Wow..thank you so much Sir. This was something I was looking for. Thanks a lot. Your answers are so clear and upto the mark:)